# Truncating magento text

Tags: php, magento, truncate

I am printing the customers email address in the header like so:

```
<?php echo $email=$this->__('Hello, %s', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEmail()); ?>
```

However I want to truncate this to a certain number due to users with long email addresses.

I have tried to use the truncate helper which magento has but I am getting no joy, wondering if anyone can help.

```
<?php echo $email=$this->__('Hello, %s', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEmail()->truncate('text', 12)); ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: If you use truncate it will remove certain portion but i don't think good idea .As if email is `abacdkdslsdfkjdfss@yahoo.com` and you are trying to show first 12 it will show `abacdkdslsdfk`.this is ok for you ?

Comment: Yes do you have a solution for that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok if that ok then you are doing in wrong way.For truncate using Magento you should try like this :

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate('abacdkdslsdfkjdfss@yahoo.com', 12); ?>
```

AS for you email concerned you can try like this : User proper email getter function .you can assign that to any variable instead of `echo`

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEmail(), 12); ?>
```

OUTPUT : `abacdkdslsdf`

First parameter will be your string and second will be length of that text.Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks, that looks good if I was printing a hard coded email however how would I apply that too:

<?php echo $email=$this->__('Hello, %s', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEmail()); ?>

Comment: Hello, thanks for the example however this gives me a white screen :(

Comment: Try to enable logs i think your email code is not working fine.catch email and then pass that to truncate function.